# Can the second term of the Schur complement of a symmetric matrix be undefined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Given the next symmetric matrix conformably partitioned

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A &B  \\ B^T  &C
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that $A$ and $C$ are positive definite matrices.

The Schur complement is $S=C-B^TA^{-1}B$

What can I say about $B^TA^{-1}B$? Is this undefined in general? or it is positive/negative (semi)definite.

Probably it is an easy question, but I do not see why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \succ 0$, $S$ is positive semidefinite iff the block matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: I asked the wrong question sorry. I meant $B^TA^{-1}B$

Comment: That is always positive semidefinite. Furthermore, if $B$ has full column rank, it is positive definite.

Comment: Why is that? I can not see it directly.

Comment: $A$ being positive definite means $A^{-1}$ is positive definite. Then define $Bx \triangleq y$, so we have  $x^TB^TA^{-1}Bx  = y^TA^{-1}y$, so positive semidefiniteness follows from positive definiteness of $A^{-1}$. The degenerate case possibly occurs if $B$ does not have full column rank ($y$ could be zero even if $x$ is not).